# How to create an abstract method with a parameter of type of implementing class

Tags: c#, generics, abstract

I have got a abstract class with an abstract method taking a parameter of the type of the implementing class. I can achieve this by generics like this:

```cs
abstract class Clazz<T>
{
   public abstract void CopyFrom(Clazz<T> source);
}

class MyClass : Clazz<MyClass>
{
  public override void CopyFrom(Clazz<MyClass>)
  {
    // implementation
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I need in one of the implementing classes a list of `Clazz<T>` elements.
So how can I achieve this?

- Of cause `List<Clazz<T>>` does not work.
- `List<Clazz<MyClass>>` is too restrictive.
- Removing the generics and the abstract method does work (my current solution), but this way I could forget to implement the `CopyFrom()` method in one of the implementing classes.

**Edit: Here comes a more detailed example:**
I've got an abstract class:

```cs
abstract class Clazz<T>
{
    public abstract void CopyFrom(Clazz<T> source);
    // ...
}
```

And a derived class:

```cs
class MyDerivedClass : Clazz<MyDerivedClass >
{
    public string Text;
    private readonly List<MySubClass> _list = new List<MySubClass>();

    public override void CopyFrom(MyDerivedClass source)
    {
        Text = source.Text;
    }

    private List<Clazz> GetAllItems()
    {
        List<Clazz> list = new List<Clazz>();
        list.Add(this);
        list.AddRange(_list);
    }


    private class MySubClass : Clazz<MySubClass>
    {
        public int Number;

        public override void CopyFrom(MySubClass source)
        {
            Number = source.Number;
        }
    }
}
```

There are several other deriving classes, the `GetAllItems()` Method is only needed in `MyDerivedClass`.

Comment: Where do you need the list? As the parameter to the abstract method, or just as a field/property in the derived class?

Comment: please can you explain why `List<Clazz<MyClass>>` is too restrictive?

Comment: `List<Clazz<MyClass>>`is too restrictive, as I need to fill it with elements of different type, all deriving from `Clazz<T>`.

Comment: I need the list only as a field in the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the respective method generic, too, and introduce a constraint that takes `T` into account. If I understand well what you want to achieve, you can do this:

```
abstract class Clazz<T>
{
   public abstract void CopyFrom(Clazz<T> source);

   public abstract void ProcessList<TDescendant>(List<TDescendant> list)
       where TDescendant : Clazz<T>;
}

class MyClass : Clazz<MyClass>
{
    public override void CopyFrom(Clazz<MyClass> source)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public override void ProcessList<TDescendant>(List<TDescendant> list)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

You can also easily include list processing in a descendant, like this:

```
class MyOtherClass : Clazz<MyOtherClass>
{
    public override void CopyFrom(Clazz<MyOtherClass> source)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    // this list processing is inherited
    public override void ProcessList<TDescendant>(List<TDescendant> list)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    // this list processing is specific to this descendant only
    public void ProcessMyClassList<TDescendant>(List<TDescendant> list)
        where TDescendant : Clazz<TMyClass>
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Then use can declare a descendant of `MyClass`, which in turn is a `Clazz<T>`, `T` being `MyClass`:

```
class MyDescendant : MyClass
{ 
}
```

The following works:

```
List<MyDescendant> list = new List<MyDescendant>();
new MyClass().ProcessList(list);
```

In case of `MyOtherClass`, the situation is a little bit different. `ProcessMyClassList` accepts a list of `Clazz<T>` or its descendants; however, not those related to `MyOtherClass` but to the good-ol' `MyClass`. This code works:

```
List<MyDescendant> list = new List<MyDescendant>();
new MyOtherClass().ProcessMyClassList(list); // this works
```

But the following won't compile:

```
List<MyOtherClass> list = new List<MyOtherClass>();
new MyOtherClass().ProcessList(list);        // this works
new MyOtherClass().ProcessMyClassList(list); // this doesn't
```

Comment: I've not tested this yet, but this way I would have to implement the method `ProcessList`in all derived classes, haven't I? As I already answered a question above, I do need the List only in one one the derived classes.

Comment: So then declare it just in the derived class :-)

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit slow-wittet, but could you modify your example to show me what you mean? Leave the method unimplemented in the other deriving classes, or remove the abstract definition from Clazz?

Comment: @Tarkil Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

would this suffice? without more details it is hard to tell.

```
interface ICopyMaker
{
    void CopyFrom(ICopyMaker source);
}

abstract class Clazz<T> : ICopyMaker
{
   public abstract void CopyFrom(Clazz<T> source);

   void ICopyMaker.CopyFrom(ICopyMaker source)
   {
       var src = source as Clazz<T>;
       if (src == null) return; // know how to copy only from the instances of the same type

       CopyFrom(src);
   }
}

class MyClass : Clazz<MyClass>
{
    private List<ICopyMaker> _list = new List<ICopyMaker>();

    public override void CopyFrom(Clazz<MyClass> c)
    {
    //implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `CopyFrom(Clazz<MyClass> c)` has no access to the fields of `MyClass : Clazz<MyClass>`. (cannot resolve symbol).

Comment: CopyFrom(Clazz<MyClass> c) is a method declared in MyClass. It always has access to any member of MyClass. Could you please provide more details on the error you arre getting?

Answer (score 0):

Thank's everyone for your answers, but I think I have figured out a solution I can live with:
I will remove the generics and add a typecheck, like in the solution from anikiforov:

Abstract class:

```
abstract class Clazz
{
   public abstract void CopyFrom(Clazz source);
}
```

And the derived class:

```
class MyDerivedClass : Clazz
{
    public string Text;
    private List<MyNestedClass> _list;

    public override void CopyFrom(Clazz source)
    {
        var src = source as MyDerivedClass;
        if (src == null) return;
        Text = src.Text;
    }

    public List<Clazz> GetAllItems()
    {
        var list = new List<Clazz>();
        list.Add(this);
        list.AddRange(_list);
        return list;
    }

    class MyNestedClass : Clazz
    {
        public int Number;
        public override void CopyFrom(Clazz source)
        {
            var src = source as MyNestedClass;
            if (src == null) return;
            Number = src.Number;
        }
    }
}
```